# Cannot compile in Katalon Studio after updating Java

Tags: java, katalon-studio

I am using katalon studio for automation testing and after updating my java applet on my pc, i cannot compile my code due to this error

> The JAR file c:\groovy-1ll-2.4.7.jar has no source attachment

Comment: How can you actually compile your code here? Does this approach have any revelation to current Katalon Studio capabilities or not? I believe Katalon Studio does not provide any proper way to compile code or claim to support this capability.

Comment: Hi vinh Nguyen, what am trying to say is running my script

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of it? Does It always happen when you execute your script?

Comment: Have you imported some external jar files?